# Unable to view LastItem In JscrollPane

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

[image]

I am unable to scroll to the last item in the above scrollbar . Please help....Thanks in Advance

The code:

```
JList myAvailableList = new JList();
myAvailableList.setName("AvailableList");
myAvailableList.addListSelectionListener(this);

JScrollPane myAvailableScroll = new JScrollPane(myAvailableList);
myAvailableScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
myAvailableScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
myAvailableScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LIST_PREF_WIDTH, LIST_PREF_HEIGHT));
```

Comment: for better help sooner please edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demostrated your issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: I have posted the code . Can you help now

Comment: stupid question, last added Item isn't accesible by mouse scrolling ???, or programatically from code ???

Comment: @mKorbel I dint get what you mean't?

Comment: code posted here talking about nothing, then my question is scrolling to the last Item in the JList available by using mouse???

Comment: Also, please learn how to use the code formatting facility.

Comment: `setPreferredSize(..`  Better to use `list.setVisibleRowCount(n)` as shown by mKorbel.  That would generally mean it is not needed to set a size (or preferred size) for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the scrollbar shows you did scroll to the last item, however the lower area of the list is hidden by a different Component, either make the list component shorter or the area containing it larger.

Answer (score 3):

For [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) you can to set [JList#ensureIndexIsVisible(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#ensureIndexIsVisible%28int%29) for scrolling to the last added `Item`

code example from [JList tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/* ListDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class ListDemo extends JPanel implements ListSelectionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JList list;
    private DefaultListModel listModel;
    private static final String hireString = "Hire";
    private static final String fireString = "Fire";
    private JButton fireButton;
    private JTextField employeeName;

    public ListDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel.addElement("Jane Doe");
        listModel.addElement("John Smith");
        listModel.addElement("Kathy Green");

        //Create the list and put it in a scroll pane.
        list = new JList(listModel);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        JButton hireButton = new JButton(hireString);
        HireListener hireListener = new HireListener(hireButton);
        hireButton.setActionCommand(hireString);
        hireButton.addActionListener(hireListener);
        hireButton.setEnabled(false);

        fireButton = new JButton(fireString);
        fireButton.setActionCommand(fireString);
        fireButton.addActionListener(new FireListener());

        employeeName = new JTextField(10);
        employeeName.addActionListener(hireListener);
        employeeName.getDocument().addDocumentListener(hireListener);
        String name = listModel.getElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex()).toString();

        //Create a panel that uses BoxLayout.
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonPane.add(fireButton);
        buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPane.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        buttonPane.add(employeeName);
        buttonPane.add(hireButton);
        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    class FireListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //This method can be called only if
            //there's a valid selection
            //so go ahead and remove whatever's selected.
            int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
            listModel.remove(index);
            int size = listModel.getSize();
            if (size == 0) { //Nobody's left, disable firing.
                fireButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else { //Select an index.
                if (index == listModel.getSize()) {
                    //removed item in last position
                    index--;
                }
                list.setSelectedIndex(index);
                list.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
            }
        }
    }

    //This listener is shared by the text field and the hire button.
    class HireListener implements ActionListener, DocumentListener {

        private boolean alreadyEnabled = false;
        private JButton button;

        public HireListener(JButton button) {
            this.button = button;
        }

        //Required by ActionListener.
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = employeeName.getText();

            //User didn't type in a unique name...
            if (name.equals("") || alreadyInList(name)) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                employeeName.requestFocusInWindow();
                employeeName.selectAll();
                return;
            }

            int index = list.getSelectedIndex(); //get selected index
            if (index == -1) { //no selection, so insert at beginning
                index = 0;
            } else { //add after the selected item
                index++;
            }

            listModel.insertElementAt(employeeName.getText(), index);
            //If we just wanted to add to the end, we'd do this:
            //listModel.addElement(employeeName.getText());
            //Reset the text field.
            employeeName.requestFocusInWindow();
            employeeName.setText("");
            //Select the new item and make it visible.
            list.setSelectedIndex(index);
            list.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
        }

        //This method tests for string equality. You could certainly
        //get more sophisticated about the algorithm.  For example,
        //you might want to ignore white space and capitalization.
        protected boolean alreadyInList(String name) {
            return listModel.contains(name);
        }

        //Required by DocumentListener.
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            enableButton();
        }

        //Required by DocumentListener.
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            handleEmptyTextField(e);
        }

        //Required by DocumentListener.
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            if (!handleEmptyTextField(e)) {
                enableButton();
            }
        }

        private void enableButton() {
            if (!alreadyEnabled) {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        private boolean handleEmptyTextField(DocumentEvent e) {
            if (e.getDocument().getLength() <= 0) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                alreadyEnabled = false;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //This method is required by ListSelectionListener.
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

            if (list.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                //No selection, disable fire button.
                fireButton.setEnabled(false);

            } else {
                //Selection, enable the fire button.
                fireButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ListDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new ListDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail

Comment: @Rekha that's very clear described in the JList tutorial inc code example

Comment: @mKorBel The docs for ensureIndexIsvisible says that "for the method to work JList must be within JViewPort" . Can you please explain or give code snippet

Comment: *"Can you please explain or give code snippet"*  Can you please post an SSCCE of your best attempt?  SO is not a code generation machine.  If you cannot figure it out from the comprehensive advice at the end of those links, the onus is on you to *motivate* people to provide further help.  That is often easy to do by posting your best attempt along with a specific question.

Comment: @mKorbel  I am wondering when you intend to start linking to the version 7 docs.  Any time soon?  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson you're right, I thinking about that long time

Comment: This wont work, the list already shows the last item, however the area containing it is cut off at the bottom (the lower arrow of the scrollbar is only half shown).

Comment: @josefx  I'm trying to understand how your comment makes sense.  The code posted works just fine on this machine.  If the OP's code doesn't, they need to post *that* code before we can see what they are doing wrong.  Further speculation beyond that, is pointless.

Comment: *"I have posted the code"*  Nobody asked for 'the code'. Please follow the link to the SSCCE made on the first comment to this question.  **Read it.**  Prepare and post an ***SSCCE!***

Comment: @AndrewThompson I referred to the screenshot posted by Rekha, scrolling to the item wont help, the lower area of the JList is cut of by the gui and with it any hope of seeing the last item on it.

Comment: @josefx at 90pct of cases weren't possible answering questions without shots to the dark, that reasons why we asked for SSCCE

Comment: @mKorbel never said anything against SSCCE, just answered AdrewThompsons question about what I referred to and the JList missing its lower arrow button is not a shot in the dark.